# Upgrade Android Studio 3, and logcat screen was modified

Tags: android, android-studio-3.0

Upgrade Android Studio 3, and logcat screen was modified, now i can't see the log filter. Does't enter in the width screen:

Old Version, in two lines, because have "logcat" and "monitors"

link Image:

[image]

New Version, not have "logcat" and "monitors", so don't enter in widht ("verbose, search, regex, no filters")

link Image:

[image]

I do not know if something similar happens to someone,thanks.

Comment: That would appear to be due to the combination of a small monitor and a seriously long device identifier, combined with the redesign. You might consider filing an issue about this, as I do not think that this is configurable.

Answer (score 1):

I noticed the same and then stumbled upon the documentations regarding this. As per [android developers guide](https://developer.android.com/studio/profile/am-basics.html), `Android Monitor` was removed from `studio 3.0` in favor of [Android profiler](https://developer.android.com/studio/profile/android-profiler.html).